# Accessing model fields in django template

Tags: django, templates, model

I am trying to access a model field inside a template.  I am using this field inside an if statement:

```
{% for event in events %}
{% if event.homepage == 'False' %}
  <tr class='teamRow'>
    <td id='day' class="rowCell">
      {{ event.date }} {{ event.homepage }}
    </td>
  </tr>
{% else %}
  <p>Else</p>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The if statement is not true.  I know it is true because {{ event.homepage }} returns "False".

The event model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    homepage = models.BooleanField()
```

I pass it the model here in my views:

```
def renderHomeNew(request):
events = Event.objects.all()
t = get_template('base_home_new.html')
context = {
    'events': events
    }
c = template.Context(context)
r = t.render(c)
return HttpResponse(r)
```

Am not following correct syntax here?  I get no errors.

Comment: Are you looping over the `events` objects?

Comment: Yes I am.  Right before the if statement: {%for event in events%}

Comment: Seems pretty valid to me. Can you show the `Event`-model, specifically the `homepage` field?

Comment: Why is you compare boolean field with a string? Why just not `{% if not event.homepage %}`?

Comment: could it be because you have it as a string? Try `{% if event.homepage == False %}` or better yet `{% if not event.homepage %}`

Comment: Generally in python and django you want to avoid doing some_var == True or False. Just use {% if event.homepage %}

Comment: @PT114, I think, this expression should be avoided for _all_ programming languages :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to compare a boolean value to a string. Your `Event`-model's `homepage` is a `BooleanField`. Try:

```
{% if not event.homepage %}
```

See also:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#boolean-operators
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.BooleanField